# How do I use Python to open chromebook apps?

Tags: python

In essence I have a chromebook instead of a Windows or Apple computer. I have Linux turned on on my chromebook, and I have Python installed to the Linux drive. Currently I'm working on a Python bot for personal use, and I want to be able to open apps on my chromebook by typing in commands. How can I achieve this? (I.E. I want to be able to open messenger by typing in "messenger").

Comment: What have you tried? We won’t write your code *for* you - see [ask]

Comment: I've tried os.open(app name here), and os.startfile(), but I don't know what I'm doing. Nor do I know how to find the app's directory. I've never been able to open apps or files using python before, (mostly because I learned python on mobile and didn't really have much use for opening files and it was a pain to try to open files on mobile). I'm not asking you to write my code for me, but I want to know how to open apps using python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Even though I am on a Windows 10 machine, I think this approach might work for Linux machines also.
 So, I tried  `os.system()` and it seems to work.
The syntax is : `os.system("Command name(String)")`
The commands are the one you input into the terminal
For example,
I used:

```
import os
os.system("cmd")
```

to open command prompt in Windows.

And:

```
os.system("calc")
```

to open Calculator

Comment: I tried that and it still isn't working. I have linux running in the background but the majority of the apps on my chromebook are android. Chrome is one of the few that aren't android and os.system("chrome") and os.system("Chrome") don't work.

Comment: Maybe it only works for System apps then

Comment: Maybe. I've tried terminal and other system apps, though, and I still can't get it to work. Do you have any other ideas?